# How to fix JPA/Hibernate error, can't find table info?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have connected my database to my main Java application using JPA/Hibernate. I am able to add/remove items from my Microsoft SQL table via my Spring boot project. Though when it comes time to view everything in my table I get an error. I attached below some more code that is associated with the project.

**Entity Class:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "taddm")
public class AVSApplication {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "appcode")
    private String mAppCode;

    @Column(name = "acro")
    private String mAcronym;

    @Column(name = "appname")
    private String mAppName;


    //Constructor
    public AVSApplication(String mAppCode, String mAcronym, String mAppName) {
        super();
        this.mAppCode = mAppCode;
        this.mAcronym = mAcronym;
        this.mAppName = mAppName;
    }


    //Default Constructor
    public AVSApplication () {

    }


    //Getters
    public String getmAppCode() {
        return mAppCode;
    }

    public String getmAcronym() {
        return mAcronym;
    }
    public String getmAppName() {
        return mAppName;
    }



    //Setters
    public void setmAcronym(String mAcronym) {
        this.mAcronym = mAcronym;
    }
    public void setmAppCode(String mAppCode) {
        this.mAppCode = mAppCode;
    }

    public void setmAppName(String mAppName) {
        this.mAppName = mAppName;
    }




}
```

**Controller:**

```
//Select
        @GetMapping("/select-me")
        public String selectApplication() {

            System.out.println(mAppRepo.findAll());
            System.out.println(mAppRepo.findById("3A0"));

           return "tier";
        }
```

**Error:**

```
Hibernate: select avsapplica0_.appcode as appcode1_0_, avsapplica0_.acro as acro2_0_, avsapplica0_.appname as appname3_0_ from taddm avsapplica0_
[]
Hibernate: select avsapplica0_.appcode as appcode1_0_0_, avsapplica0_.acro as acro2_0_0_, avsapplica0_.appname as appname3_0_0_ from taddm avsapplica0_ where avsapplica0_.appcode=?
Optional.empty
```

**Repo:**

```
@Repository
public interface AppRepository extends JpaRepository<AVSApplication, String>{

     @Override
     List<AVSApplication> findAll();

}
```

**Table Names:**

```
appcode (primary key)
acro
appname
```

Comment: Show the full code of your Entity and Repository here. Also what is the exact table name(s)?

Comment: @AjayKumar Ok, I added the code for the repository,entity and table names.

Comment: I do not see an error in the "Error" bloc in your question. It is just showing that Hibernate did not find anything in the database (hence empty array and Optional.empty). Could you post the stack trace of the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

I thought so. Its NOT an error. A valid output in fact. You are trying to query (sysout) appcode - "3A0" which doesn not exist. I tried to replicate the same on my local and I was able to do it by querying an non existing appcode as under:

Invalid input:

```
System.out.println(mAppRepo.findAll());
System.out.println(mAppRepo.findById("appcode"));
```

output:

```
[com.example.demo.entity.AVSApplication@1640ad08]
Optional.empty
```

Valid input:

```
System.out.println(mAppRepo.findAll());
    System.out.println(mAppRepo.findById("abc"));
```

output:

```
[com.example.demo.entity.AVSApplication@335bed5b]
Optional[com.example.demo.entity.AVSApplication@655967a5]
```

So make sure you are querying an existing and valid criteria. Look for typos and try again.

Comment: Thanks for even replying back, but even when I do the ```findAll()``` method it still doesn't work. Since it takes no parameters I use the method as a test.

Comment: findAll() gives you Iterable. Take a look here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `override` default `findAll()` method under `JpaRepository`. Just keep the repository interface empty.

```
@Repository
public interface AppRepository extends JpaRepository<AVSApplication, String>{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown, it seems there is no error in your code instead, it didn't find anything with that key of `findById("your_key")` and you don't have value for that key.
What you can do is check if you have value for that key like this an act accordingly:

```
Optional<AVSApplication> optionalApp = mAppRepo.findById("3A0");
if (optionalApp.isPresent()) 
    {
        AVSApplication yourObject= optionalApp.get();
     } 
else 
    {
        //throw new exceptions or do whatever you want
    }
```

Moreover, clear your override `findAll()` method from your repository